# Cannot use python-geoip with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, geoip

Python-Geoip is a small package that allows free offline use of the MaxMind country database. It works fine locally, but I cannot get it working within AWS Lambda.

I created a deployment package with `requests`, `geoip` and `geoip-geolite2`, but I am getting the following error message:

> "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'uploadXmlLog'"

If I comment out `requests` I get the error message:

> "errorMessage": "Cannot use packaged database \"geolite2\" because package \"_geoip_geolite2\" is not available. It's provided by PyPI package \"python-geoip-geolite2\""

Using `requests` without `geoip` works fine.

How can I resolve this?

[Deployment package contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3avdN.png)

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, sorry.  Content of some inner folders wasn't included to deployment package.  Need to use 'zip -r ... ' creating development package. 
BTW due to geoip db deployment package increases to ~18 Mb and AWS doesn't allow you to edit python files online. But works fine.